# For which $a,b\in \mathbb{N},$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{b}}$ is a rational number.

Tags: contest-math, fractions, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

I found the following problem on a Olympiad question paper:

For which $a,b\in \mathbb{N},$ is $$\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{b}}$$ a rational number.

I am unable to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try "rationalizing the denominator"?

Answer (score 4):

Well, $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{b}}
~=~& \dfrac{(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{b})}{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{b})} & \textsf{except when }b=3
\\[2ex] =~&\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3a}-\sqrt{2b}-\sqrt{ab}}{3-b}
\end{align}$$

Then, when might this be rational? ...

Comment: Small fix; $3-b$ on the denominator.

Comment: f course it is.

Comment: If $b=3$, we can still rationalize the denominator by multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{3}$., getting $\frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{3a}}{6}$.  A subproblem is then to show when $\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{3a}$ is rational for natural number $a$.